# Slony with Amazon's RDS service?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws, amazon-ec2, slony

Is it actually possible to somehow use Slony with Amazon’s RDS service? I’m aware that there’s no such thing as a host that you can log into to make Slony’s configurations, but perhaps it can be done remotely from a side server or something like that?

Comment: Not certain about Slony, but AWS added support for the session replication role sometime around Nov. 2014, and advertised that it should be usable with Londiste and Bucardo: [ref](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/rds-postgres-read-replicas/)

Comment: Looks like Slony is a [no](http://slony1-general.slony.narkive.com/NIeO1nz8/rds-postgresql) for now

Comment: Wasn't aware of Londiste and Bucardo, will have to check/study those @JoshKupershmidt